# selenium find link within `li` tag and click

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium in python to click on `Annual Report` in the below `html` extract.

However, `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Annual Reports").click()` does not seem to work. the error message I get is `Unable to locate element:`

I have also tried:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('url'):
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

But this returns `None`

What should I do instead in order to get selenium to click on this link?

```
<li class="sic_fundamental selected">
    <a href="/fundamental/factsheet.html">Fundamental</a>
      <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/fundamental/events_calendar.html">
              <span class="url">Events Calendar</span>
              <div class="description">Compilation of Corporate Actions like Dividend, Rights and Bonus Issues and Financial Result release dates. Keep abreast of stock events for the day and react accordingly to different events.</div>
            </a>
            <div class="subNav"><a href="/fundamental/events_calendar.html#/?type=events_upcoming" class="first-child">Upcoming</a><a href="/fundamental/events_calendar.html#/?type=events_exdates">Ex-Dates</a><a href="/fundamental/events_calendar.html#/?type=events_results">Results Release</a></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/fundamental/dividend_analysis.html">
              <span class="url">Dividend Analysis</span>
              <div class="description">Research the best high yield stocks by analysing the dividend history of each company and gain new insights into the dividend trend using our financial charts.</div>
            </a>
            <div class="subNav"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/fundamental/annual_reports.html">
              <span class="url">Annual Reports</span>
              <div class="description">Browse through our complete catalog of Annual Reports for listed companies</div>
            </a>
            <div class="subNav"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/fundamental/stocks_comparison.html">
              <span class="url">Stocks Comparison</span>
              <div class="description">Do a comparison of different stocks to find out which one is better. Compare the fundamentals and financials of different stocks.</div>
            </a>
            <div class="subNav"><a href="/fundamental/stocks_comparison.html#/?type=compare_stocks" class="first-child">Compare Stocks</a><a href="/fundamental/stocks_comparison.html#/?type=compare_warrants">Compare Warrants</a></div>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: try with this xpath ->"//span[contains(text(),'Annual Reports']"

Comment: its the xpath of the element. It identifies the element with tag name span and containing text Annual Reports.

Comment: This is the error that I get from XPath expression - `The string '//span[contains(text(),'Annual Reports']' is not a valid XPath expression.`. Might it be because I am using Google Chrome?

Comment: sorry, there was a typo ->"//span[contains(text(),'Annual Reports')]"........use double quotes while enclosing the xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual link text is not "Annual Reports" but "Annual Reports
Browse through our complete catalog of Annual Reports for listed companies", so you might try to match required link by just partial text:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Annual Reports").click()
```

If you still get `Unable to locate element` try to wait some time for required element to appear in `DOM` as it might be generated dinamically:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 10).until(elemenet_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Annual Reports"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But it still returns an error `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:` I typed exactly as you have mentioned

Comment: Try updated code. Also check if the list of links not located inside an `iframe`

Comment: Thanks. This works. I suppose it would be good to have a `wait` in place